# Mobile Automation Tool

Tags: unit-testing, mobile, automation, functional-testing, seetest

Please let me know which is the best automation Tool for Mobile Native application.

We have two Choices 1. DeviceAnywhere 2. SeeTest.

Please provide the positive and negative points of the tool.

Regards,
Rahul Mendiratta

Answer (score 2):

The only person who should answer that question is you; what you really need to ask yourselves is which is the best tool for you and no one else can answer that. Teams will have different answers to which is the best tool in a certain category based on their experience, requirements and expectations.

If youre consdiering test automation tools you need to carry out a detailed evaluation where you need to consider the following areas (and this list is by no means exhaustive).

1. Budget (time and money)
2. Coding experience
3. Test automation experience available Who is going to write the tests
4. Level of support required for the tool Software development
   practices / methodology in place in your team / department /
   organisation
5. Target Devices
6. AUT